# Where can I find historical presidential approval ratings

Tags: data-request, polling

I'm looking for data on presidential approval polls going back as far as possible. Gallup has this data, but is not available to public. (http://news.gallup.com/interactives/185273/presidential-job-approval-center.aspx)

There is also data available from The American Presidency Project (http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/data/popularity.php?pres=45&sort=time&direct=DESC&Submit=DISPLAY), but the site doesn't provide a link to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tweak the url for The American Presidency Project to get the data on a specific president.  For example, here's the url for Obama:
http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/data/popularity.php?pres=44&sort=time&direct=DESC&Submit=DISPLAY

Scraping the data from that site is pretty simple depending on your tools.  You could also easily copy & paste the table into a spreadsheet, if scraping isn't your thing.